Where are the forecasted predictions for time series forecasting with PathTSMixerPredicition transformer?
I am trying to do a time series forecast prediction and using the PathTSMixer transformer model with the patch_tsmisxer_getting_started.ipynb tutorial. I've trained the model and everything seems to be working but I do not understand the output. It outputs 4 arrays but I have no idea what they are. Which one is the prediction? None of them look anywhere close to what I expected, are the outputs normalized?
output = trainer.predict(test_dataset)
output.predictions


